# Circuit to supply stable 12vdc from an automotive battery to opamp rails

Tags: automotive

I've created an Automotive IO board that has digital inputs, digital outputs, analog inputs and analog outputs. Onboard I have an automotive grade regulator to convert the dirty 12vdc to a clean 3.3v for the io circuitry. Howver, the Analog output opamps require at least 12v for the rails. I'm looking for a way to get a stable 12vdc supply to connect to the rails of my opamps.
Any ideas?

opamps im using are - LM2904AVQDR

Answer (score 2):

Use a boost-buck regulator ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter)). This can give you a steady 12 volts through the normal range of an automotive electrical system. If you need cleaner power, use it to raise the output to a steady 15 volts (for example) and follow it will a low-noise LDO to get your 12 volts.